# How to find the longest consecutive chain of numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays

For example we have `[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]` .

The result must be `7, 8, 9, 10` because they are adjacent to each other, index wise and are consecutive integers, and also this chain is longer than `0, 1`.

English is not my first language, excuse me if the writing is a bit obscure.

Comment: Some kind of code golf or homework here

Comment: It's not homework, I'm trying to solve a problem using this method but can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Using for loop: if n < n+1, but I need to include bigger by one, because this way all the successive numbers are <

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group the items into subsequences using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) based on  constant differences from an increasing count (provided by an [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) object), and then take the longest subsequence using the built-in `max` on *key* parameter `len`:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

lst = [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]
c = count()
val = max((list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x-next(c))), key=len)
print(val)
# [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You may include the group key in the result (suppressed as `_`) to further understand how this works.

Comment: This is seriously awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) module:

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.array([0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13])
longest_seq = max(np.split(nums, np.where(np.diff(nums) != 1)[0]+1), key=len).tolist()    
print(longest_seq)
```

The output:

```
[7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

- `np.where(np.diff(nums) != 1)[0]+1` - gets the indices of elements on which the array should be split (if difference between 2 consequtive numbers is not equal to `1`, e.g. `3` and `5`)
- `np.split(...)` - split the array into sub-arrays

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html#numpy.diff
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.split.html

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (similar to @Moses Koledoye's answer):

```
groups = [[y[1] for y in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(iterable), key=lambda x: x[0]-x[1])]
groups
# [[0, 1], [3], [5], [7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13]]

max(groups, key=len)
# [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

*Alternative*

Consider the third-party tool [`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups):

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]
max((list(g) for g in mit.consecutive_groups(iterable)), key=len)
# [7, 8, 9, 10]
```